# Return List using foreach

Tags: c#, foreach, json.net

```
public string Studentbyteacher(long _id)
{
    using (var context = new DbContext())
    {
        var studentID = (context.TeacherStudent.Where(x => x.TeacherID == _id).Select(x => x.studentID));
        foreach (var id in studentID)
        {
            var strJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(context.Student.Where(x => x.ID == id).ToList());
            return strJSON;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note: I am getting student ID in array list like [0]1,[1]2,[2]3...so on. So I want to return student details on the basis of ID. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted? What's the current output? What's the expected output? This questions lacks detail.

Comment: Please edit your question to *actually* ask a question

Comment: You could almost simplify the whole lot down to `return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(context.TeacherStudent.Where(x => x.TeacherID == _id).Select(x => x.studentID)).FirstOrDefault());`  .. but Im assuming you meant you wanted more than one line back

Comment: You can only do one return per function per code path, you have a return in a foreach loop.  It would never get past the first iteration of the loop doing it this way.

Comment: Right now i am getting only 1 student value on the basis of their ID, but i want to return list of student on the basis of their id. like  :                      [1 student1 0 Address1 
2 student2 0 Address2 
3 student3 0 Address3 
4 student4 0 Address4 ]

Comment: @SahilSharma you need to edit the question and make it more clear, don't try to have us parse through a conversation of comments to try to understand your question as a whole... update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public string Studentbyteacher(long teacherId)
{
    using (var context = new DbContext())
    {
        var students = 
            from teacherStudent in context.TeacherStudent.Where(x => x.TeacherID == teacherId)
            let studentId = teacherStudent.studentID
            let student = context.Student.Where(x => x.ID == studentId).Single()
            select student;

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(students);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the yield return which you can use to return a `IEnumerable< T >` or `IEnumerable` in a loop.

First you would need to change your method to:

```
 public IEnumerable<string> Studentbyteacher(long _id)
```

and change the line

```
var strJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(context.Student.Where(x => x.ID == id).ToList());
```

to

```
yield return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(context.Student.Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault());
```

and finally delete `return strJson;`